How to repro kernel writing a dirty page build-up to disk while throttling writes from processes?
Or how to repro a situation where nr_dirty > nr_dirty_threshold?
What parameters can I tweak? From the default:
vm.dirty_background_ratio=10
vm.dirty_ratio=20

I switched to:
vm.dirty_background_ratio=1
vm.dirty_ratio=50

hoping that by limiting background write backs to disk, I'll make the dirty pages pile up, and eventually it will reach a point where the nr_dirty would cross the threshold and force the kernel to block the processes' IO.
I am running an fio load on this machine so that the writes are coming in heavy (driving up dirty pages). But kernel seems to remove the dirty pages periodically, and never lets the nr_dirty climb beyond the dirty threshold:
2024-08-15 04:38:06
nr_dirty 1904664
nr_writeback 10783
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2542494
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27590

2024-08-15 04:38:07
nr_dirty 1912333
nr_writeback 15478
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2552186
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27695

2024-08-15 04:38:08
nr_dirty 1923568
nr_writeback 14103
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2551530
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27688

2024-08-15 04:38:09
nr_dirty 1948670
nr_writeback 14822
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2534651
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27505

2024-08-15 04:38:10
nr_dirty 1935645
nr_writeback 16322
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2540601
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27570

2024-08-15 04:38:11
nr_dirty 1942668
nr_writeback 6385
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_dirty_threshold 2542122
nr_dirty_background_threshold 27586


Any other parameters I can change? Or do something else with the fio load?
Config I'm using now:
[global]
ioengine=libaio
size=16G
rw=write
iodepth=32
numjobs=4
runtime=2700
time_based
group_reporting


[high_bw_test]
direct=0
bs=1M
rate_iops=4096
filename=/var/lib/ssd_mount_point/test_file.fio


Not sure if it matters, but the disk is an SSD (a P20 from Azure)
Problem X: Why is the requirement so specific? I'm trying to repro an issue with another userspace process which only manifests when nr_dirty > nr_dirty_threshold (or so I suspect, and it seems to hold true when it happens naturally in production about once a day). Basically I think the kernel seems to be choking I/O from my process (while the kernel is trying to flush the dirty pages since it has crossed the dirty-ratio threshold). I want to get the dirty pages to cross the threshold to observe what the kernel does to my running process, and validate my hypothesis.
